# React native - undefined is not an object ('evaluating this.props.navigation')

Tags: react-native, tabs, navigation, expo, drawer

Expected behaviour: A drawer should be opened containing a menu icon in the header.

Current behaviour: Error message `undefined is not an object ('evaluating this.props.navigation')`

Searching for the error didn't help me.

I split up the navigation into two files:
*RootNavigation.js* and *MainTabNavigation*

*RootNavigation.js*

```
const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({

  Main: MainTabNavigator,
});
const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: AppNavigator
  },
  Login: {
    screen: login
  },
  Signup: {
    screen: signup
  }
});

export default class RootNavigation extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this._notificationSubscription = this._registerForPushNotifications();
  }
```

*MainTabNavigation.js*

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
});

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-home${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
          : 'md-home'
      }
    />
  ),   
};

const LinksStack = createStackNavigator({
  Links: LinksScreen,
});

LinksStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Shops',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `ios-list${focused ? '' : '-outline'}` : 'md-list'}
    />
  ),
};

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: SettingsScreen,
});

SettingsStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Cart',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `ios-cart${focused ? '' : '-outline'}` : 'md-cart'}
    />
  ),
};

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  LinksStack,
  SettingsStack,
});
```

*MainTab* file which displays an icon in the header

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) =>({
  title: 'Home',
  headerLeft: <Ionicons 
                name="md-menu" 
                size={25} 
                color="blue" 
                style={{ margin: 7,}}
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')} 
                />
});
```

Comment: Drawer did not open when i press menu icon:
error is like:
undefined is not an object ('evaluting _this2.props.navigation

Comment: `this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')` should be `navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')`.

Comment: Thanks for response. i tried navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen'). Not gettting error now. but still the problem is there: i can't open drawer with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/#using-params-in-the-title), when `navigationOptions` is used as a function, `this` does not refer to an instance of the component; so `this.props` is not available.

Instead, you will need to replace:

`this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')`

with:

`navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')`

Alternatively, you might want to use the `navigation.openDrawer()` helper as shown in the example [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html), because navigating to `DrawerOpen` is implying you want to navigate to a screen with that name.

Comment: I don't know why :D
succeeded with alter method. navigation.openDrawer().
I have tried it before that but be that time i had different problem.
Thank you sooooo much. 
#peace

Answer (score 1):

you must know this , when you create component witch class like this

```
class MyComponent extends ....
```

if you want use any props , you must write this KeyWord for example

```
this.props.navigation.nvigate()
```

but if you create component with arrow function like this

```
const Mycomponent = (props) => {}
```

you no need this KeyWord and for call props you must write like this

```
 props.navigation.navigate()
```

and in your case , if use component inside option of Navigation you no need this or props KeyWord , just write

```
 navigation.navigate()
```

Comment: Thanks for response. 
I have solved my problem with @Ezra answer.